# Merge Javascript objects, can't seem to find correct way

Tags: javascript

Hi i've been struggling a bit and i cant seem to find why the methods i found dont work, could be "fixture-0"

First Object array

```
personformdata[i]: "{"isInvalid":false,"agentRole":"role"}"
```

Second

```
address_ids[i] : "[{"address_id": "fixture-0" }]"
```

preferable out come, something like this.

```
"{"isInvalid":false,"agentRole":"role", "address_id": "fixture-0"}"
```

Comment: what you tried ,give me your code

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh http://dpaste.com/1575149/

Comment: I think one of them aint object or something. 5hrs non stop. cant think anymoar

Comment: @CD.. Duplicate does not apply.  He's having a specific problem merging, not looking for how to merge.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold Try typing one object directly into the interpreter.  See if it looks correct.

Comment: Also, put your code and a description of the error in the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like:

```
var mergedObj={};
for(var key in personformdata[i])
    mergedObj[key]=personformdata[i][key];
for(var key in address_ids[i])
    mergedObj[key]=address_ids[i][key];
```

or if you use jQuery:

```
var mergedObj={};
$.extend(mergedObj, personformdata[i], address_ids[i]);
```

I myself usually use vanilla JavaScript and prefer not using jQuery.

Comment: went with pure js as well

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

for xample you can visit this url.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new array with merged objects, just do this with a for loop:

```
        var newData = { };

        for (var i = 0; i < personformdata.length; i++)
        {
            newData[i] = { 
                isInvalid : personformdata[i].isInvalid,
                agentRole : personformdata[i].agentRole,
                address_id : address_ids[i].address_id
            };
        }
```